# Magento 2 Tooltip not working in phtml file

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

```
<?php $_content = '<img src=\"' . $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Checkout::cvv.png')) . '\" alt=\"' . $block->escapeQuote(__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) . '\" title=\"' . $block->escapeQuote(__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) . '\" />'; ?>
            <div class="note">
                <a href="#" class="action cvv" title="<?php echo $block->escapeQuote(__('What is this?')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"tooltip": {"content": "<?php echo $_content ?>"}}'><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('What is this?')) ?></span></a>
            </div>
```

This is returning the wrong URL structure before Magento_Checkout. I'm not sure how to change that.

i.e. Returns: /frontend/_view/Magento_Checkout

Should Return: /frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Checkout

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this problem in the future, this is how I fixed mine -

```
<?php $_content = '<img src=\"' . $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Checkout::cvv.png', array('area' => 'frontend', 'theme' => 'VENDER/THEME_NAME'))) . '\" alt=\"' . $block->escapeQuote(__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) . '\" title=\"' . $block->escapeQuote(__('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')) . '\" />'; ?>
        <div class="note">
            <a href="#" class="action cvv" title="<?php echo $block->escapeQuote(__('What is this?')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"tooltip": {"content": "<?php echo $_content ?>"}}'><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('What is this?')) ?></span></a>
        </div>
```